# Stop Recent Apps Icons from moving

Tags: applications

On my android phone, when i click the III icon at the bottom of the page (left of the home icon), the 4 recently used apps come up.

The problem is that there is usually a second or so delay and the icons MOVE...causing me to activate the wrong app.  Happens all the time.  Any way to stop that?